# what is the use keyword in php symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to PHP. I am trying to read the code in Symfony 2 `app`, and I am not able to understand what is this function.

Can anyone please explain to me what this function is doing. I am not able to get how is this variable defined

```
$def = function($name, $class, $args=[]) use ($container){
   return $container->doStuff($name, $class);
};
```

What is `use` doing there?

Comment: in simple words `use` makes `$container` variable available inside the anonymous function.

Comment: is this syntax of `use` from php or symfony. i havent seen `use` word after function declarartion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
$def=function($name, $class, $args=[]) use ($container){
   return $container->doStuff($name, $class);
};
```

is roughly the same than:

```
$def = my_function($container, $name, $class);

function my_function($container, $name, $class, $args=[]) {
  return $container->doStuff($name, $class);
}
```

Comment: thanks , i was going to ask that in comment that it means passing another parameter as arguments

Answer (score 0):

Use keyword used in this way

```
<?php
namespace foo;
use My\Full\Classname as Another;

// this is the same as use My\Full\NSname as NSname
use My\Full\NSname;

// importing a global class
use ArrayObject;

$obj = new namespace\Another; // instantiates object of class foo\Another
$obj = new Another; // instantiates object of class My\Full\Classname
NSname\subns\func(); // calls function My\Full\NSname\subns\func
$a = new ArrayObject(array(1)); // instantiates object of class ArrayObject
// without the "use ArrayObject" we would instantiate an object of class foo\ArrayObject
?>
```